# How to start tomcat with jsvc?

Tags: tomcat, jsvc

I'm trying to start tomcat with jsvc but it gives me this strange error

```
JSVC re-exec requires execution with an absolute or relative path
```

using

```
jsvc -debug -cp ./bin/bootstrap.jar:bin/tomcat-juli.jar \
     -outfile ./logs/catalina.out -errfile ./logs/catalina.err \
     org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just ran into this error myself. In my case, using the absolute path to jsvc --- `/usr/bin/jsvc` on my machine --- fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

I run Tomcat by double-click `startup.sh` file on `$CATALINA_HOME/bin` folder. After that, I enter this URL `http://localhost:8080/` in the browser and it runs.