# How to run nexus sonatype on port 80?

Tags: tomcat, fedora, nexus, port80

I have a fedora server. I installed tomcat via yum package manager. Then I deployed the nexus war on the webapps folder. [I tryed using jsvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136348/how-to-start-tomcat-with-jsvc) to run the server on port 80 and did not work. I saw you can also use [port fowarding](http://www.klawitter.de/tomcat80.html). What is the best alternative ?

## edit 1: httpd

I followed [3.8. Running Nexus Behind a Proxy](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html) from sonatype doc and I'm a bit confused.
I installed httpd, and I have the following configuration, where example.com is my domain.

/etc/httpd/conf.d/nexus.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName example.com
  ProxyRequests Off

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass /nexus/ http://localhost:8081/nexus/
  ProxyPassReverse /nexus/ http://localhost:8081/nexus/
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>

  ErrorLog logs/nexus/error.log
  CustomLog logs/nexus/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

/home/guillaume/www/nexus/conf

```
# Jetty section
application-port=8081
application-host=0.0.0.0
nexus-webapp=${bundleBasedir}/nexus
nexus-webapp-context-path=/nexus

# Nexus section
nexus-work=${bundleBasedir}/../sonatype-work/nexus
runtime=${bundleBasedir}/nexus/WEB-INF
pr.encryptor.publicKeyPath=/apr/public-key.txt
```

when I try to access

- `http://localhost:8081/nexus/index.html` everything work
- `http://localhost/nexus/index.html` everything work
- `http://example.com/nexus/index.html` just hang ( port 80 is open in the firewall )

  $netstat -tulpn | grep :80

  tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      3965/httpd
  tcp        0      0 :::8081                     :::*                        LISTEN      3811/java
  udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:803                 0.0.0.0:*                               1051/rpc.statd

any clue on how to make that proxy work ?

## edit 2: nginx

I found the error, the dns was wrong: `nslookup example.com` resolved to `x.x.x.x` when my ip was `x.x.x.y`

but I did enjoy ngix configuration

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        access_log off;
        error_log off;

        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://localhost:8081;
                proxy_redirect  off;

                #Proxy Settings
                proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        # would be a good idea to redirect static assets
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like running java app servers on port 80. Requires the process to be run as root.

The best approach is to install Apache (or Nginx) and configure nexus as a reverse proxy. For more details on how this is done I'd suggest reading the relevent section of the Nexus book:

- http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html

**Note**

- Lots of other advantages to setting up a reverse proxy. For example you could setup a custom 503 error message that is displayed whenever you take down Nexus for maintenance.

Comment: I also saw this http://wiki.ivonet.nl/display/LINUX/Install+or+Upgrade+Sonatype+Nexus

Comment: This answer is outdated given a world where docker exists. These days it's highly desirable to run app servers in a container on port 80.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to use [authbind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind) to get the job done (without any proxy at all). Using it for nexus it a bit tricky though, since nexus is started by a java service wrapper (jsw), which in turn is started by a startup script (which recalls itself as a different user, if desired).

The solution is as follows (relative paths are relative to the nexus home directory, `$NEXUS_HOME`):

1. in `conf/nexus.properties` set

```
application-port=80
application-host=0.0.0.0
```

(or whatever you need)

2. create a (system) user for nexus, which has a login shell (!), e.g.

   ```
   adduser --system --shell /bin/sh --no-create-home --group nexus
   ```

   (make all of the nexus files belong to the new user, e.g. `chown -R nexus:nexus .`)
   A login shell is needed, because `bin/nexus` calls `su - $RUN_AS_USER ...`, that's why the user `nexus` must be able to "login" (not really).
3. get the user id for the new user: `id -u nexus` (let's pretend it was `108`)
4. create the authbind configuration file `/etc/authbind/byuid/108` (use the nexus user's id as the file name):

```
0.0.0.0,80
::,80
```

The IP and port should be the same as used in `nexus.properties` (see step 1). The IPv6 port may or may not be needed, depends on other configuration (from Jetty). It's safe to enable it in authbind.

5. create a small helper script (needed for the jsw), put in a default executables' path (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/authbind-java`):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec authbind java "$@"
```

(make the file executable, by `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/authbind-java`)

6. edit the jsw configuration file `bin/jsw/conf/wrapper.conf`, find the setting `wrapper.java.command` (should read `java` as value) and replace the value with `authbind-java` (the helper script just written).

Now you are ready to start nexus. From nexus' home directory:

```
RUN_AS_USER=nexus bin/nexus start
```

(or edit `bin/nexus` and set `RUN_AS_USER=nexus` directly and call `bin/nexus start`)

Nexus (the jetty server) should now start, initialize and finally bind to the port 80, but still running as the "unprivileged" user `nexus`.

---

A side note: since you are binding the port 80 for nexus, it's probably running on an own (virtual) host, thus it's easily possible to designate an own domain name (eg. `nexus.example.com`) to it. When doing so, I prefer to strip the `/nexus` prefix (context path) from the URI, to save typing, it's in the domain name already. For having nexus to serve under the root, set `nexus-webapp-context-path` to `/` (in `conf/nexus.properties`). The repository path would become for example `http://nexus.example.com/content/repositories/releases` (instead of `http://nexus.example.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases`).

Answer (score 4):

How about just using iptables to redirect the port.
So nexus is still running on port 8080, but you can also access it via port 80.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i <interface> -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

See (for example) https://www.systutorials.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/ for more informations on setting this up.